# FastReport - Component TfrxPDFExport properties

Tags: delphi-xe3, fastreport

How can I set pdf orientation whether landscape or portrait using 
TfrxPDFExport component in FastReport 5 with Delphi XE3?

Answer (score 0):

FR's TfrxPDFExport uses TfrxReportPage settings for orientation, so you don't need to set any settings

Comment: TfrxReportPage is poPortrait but when I save as Pdf shows poPortrait but prints landscape

Comment: Layout of printer is portrait but OnClick to printer shows landscape.
and print on paper as landscape.

Comment: problem solved! the problem was the EndlessHeight property that was true. Thank you!